# Flask submit form without refreshing the page

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have a Flask form named form.html and I would like to print the value on the same page without refreshing the page. The form is as below:

```
<form name="my-form2" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="data" />
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I followed the Java script from https://stackoverflow.com/a/71286552/9662797 and is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(uri => {
  // Register a listener for submit events.
  const form = document.querySelector('form[name="my-form2"]');
  form.addEventListener('submit', evt => {
    // Suppress the default behavior of the form.
    evt.preventDefault();
    // Submit the form data.
    fetch(uri, {
      method: 'post',
      body: new FormData(evt.target)
    }).then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        // Handle response here.
      });
    // Reset the form.
    evt.target.reset();
  });
})({{ url_for('auth.upload')| tojson }});
```

In the app.py, I have the following view functions:

```
@auth.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
 if request.form.get('data'):
    form_value = request.form.get('data')
    print (form_value)
    
    return redirect(url_for("auth.form", form_value = form_value))



@auth.route('/form')

def form():
    passed_value = request.args.get('form_value')
    print (passed_value)
    
 
    return render_template('form.html', passed_value=passed_value)
```

On the terminal, the values of form_value and passed_value are printed with the view function. I would like to print the value of form_value to the form page like below with out refreshing:

```
 <form name="my-form2" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="data" />
  <input type="submit" />
 </form>

<h5> The submitted value is: {{passed_value}} </h5>
```

However, I am not able to print the passed_value on the form page. It prints as None.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you are using uses `jsonify` to use the JSON format for the server's response. However, you send a redirect. Thus the value of `data` remains empty.

Since you are sending a request using the Fetch API, the forwarding doesn't work. An HTTP Location header is sent back, which is ignored by the browser. But since you don't want to reload the page anyway, this is the wrong approach.

You can send the server response as JSON or HTML. Depending on the variant used, the code must be changed.

If you send a response via JSON, it is necessary to use `jsonify` on the server side.

```py
from flask import jsonify

@auth.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
 if request.form.get('data'):
    form_value = request.form.get('data')
    
    return jsonify(form_value = form_value)
```

The result is parsed on the client side and you can manually enter the returned value into the page.

```html
<h5> The submitted value is: <span id="result"><span></h5>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
(uri => {
  // Register a listener for submit events.
  const form = document.querySelector('form[name="my-form2"]');
  form.addEventListener('submit', evt => {
    // Suppress the default behavior of the form.
    evt.preventDefault();
    // Submit the form data.
    fetch(uri, {
      method: 'post',
      body: new FormData(evt.target)
    }).then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        // Handle response here.
        const elem = document.getElementById('result');
        elem && (elem.textContent = data.form_value);
      });
    // Reset the form.
    evt.target.reset();
  });
})({{ url_for('auth.upload')| tojson }});
</script>
```

For example, if you use a template with `render_template`, the result will be sent as `text/html` and you have to change the fetch call so that it no longer expects JSON but text.
Then the data can also be inserted into the page as described.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
(uri => {
  // Register a listener for submit events.
  const form = document.querySelector('form[name="my-form2"]');
  form.addEventListener('submit', evt => {
    // Suppress the default behavior of the form.
    evt.preventDefault();
    // Submit the form data.
    fetch(uri, {
      method: 'post',
      body: new FormData(evt.target)
    }).then(resp => resp.text()) // <-- !!!
      .then(text => {
        console.log(text);
        // Handle response here.
        const elem = document.getElementById('result');
        elem && (elem.innerHTML = text);
      });
    // Reset the form.
    evt.target.reset();
  });
})({{ url_for('auth.upload')| tojson }});
</script>
```

Comment: It worked using JSON response. Thank you!